# Yepnope - loads files for desktop but doesn't load files for mobile

Tags: javascript, yepnope

I've done something wrong but can't figure out what the first part of the script for desktop works and loads the scripts I want it to but when I test on mobile none of the mobile scripts get loaded! Can someone point out what I've done wrong.

Thanks

```
  <script src="/medias/custom-content/js/yepnope.1.5.4-min.js"></script>
  <script src="/medias/custom-content/js/categorizr.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

  yepnope([{
    test: categorizr.isDesktop,
    yep: ['http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jcarousel/0.3.0/jquery.jcarousel.min.js','/medias/custom-content/microsites/2014/event10/simple-sleek/desktop_carousel.js','/medias/custom-content/js/getjson.js'],
    complete: function() {
      for (i=1; i<=8; i++) {
              returnDetails("#item"+i);
      }
    }
  },
  {
    test: categorizr.isMobile,
    yep: ['/_ui/mobile/common/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js','/medias/custom-content/microsites/2014/event10/simple-sleek/mobile_carousel.js','/medias/custom-content/js/getjson_mobile.js'],
    complete: function() {
      for (i=1; i<=8; i++) {
              returnDetails("#item"+i);
      }
    }
  }
  ]);

  });

  </script>
```

Here's the script that works:-

```
  <script src="/medias/custom-content/js/yepnope.1.5.4-min.js"></script>
  <script src="/medias/custom-content/js/categorizr.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

  yepnope([{
    test: categorizr.isDesktop,
    yep: ['http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jcarousel/0.3.0/jquery.jcarousel.min.js','/medias/custom-content/microsites/2014/event10/simple-sleek/desktop_carousel.js','/medias/custom-content/js/getjson.js'],
    nope: ['/_ui/mobile/common/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js','/medias/custom-content/microsites/2014/event10/simple-sleek/mobile_carousel.js','/medias/custom-content/js/getjson_mobile.js'],
    complete: function() {
      for (i=1; i<=8; i++) {
              returnDetails("#item"+i);
      }
    }
  },
  ]);

  });

  </script>
```

Comment: Have you attempted any debugging at all?

Comment: Hi I've been debugging, and have fixed the problem. I thought the complete function only runs if the test is true but it runs whatever. So I've restructured the code (see above)